# Why can't I display my data from firebase?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem because I can’t display my data from firestore. I want to take my id from the xml. I’ve written this with help from a video and when they write the id it gets it immediately, but mine doesn’t.
[This is the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJIdHEASgu0)

**Main activity.kt**

```
private fun retrivePerson() = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
    try {
        val querySnapshot = personCollectionName.get().await()
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (document in querySnapshot.documents) {
            val users = document.toObject<users>()
            sb.append("$users\n")
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            uzytkownik.text = sb.toString()
           /* val imie = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.uzytkownik).apply {

                text = "Witaj, " + sb.toString()*/
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, e.message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
    }
```

**main xml**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uzytkownik"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Witaj,"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </ScrollView>
```

**error id user**
[image: error id user]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the video, he's using KotlinX.synthetics, which is a way to access XML view components in your code. This is actually deprecated at this point as you should use [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration) instead.